# Debian won't boot: udevd fails to load device sda and sdb

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, boot

I **can't boot my Debian** system, I got this error during boot up:

```
Driver 'pcspkr' is already registered, aborting.
```

I have solved this by adding `blacklist snd-pscp` to **/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf** ([inspired by this](http://trufelli.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/debian-driver-%E2%80%98pcspkr%E2%80%99-is-already-registered-aborting%E2%80%A6/)

Now I can't see this error during boot up, but **my computer prints this and stops** (shell not running, I can type text and it displays on screen, but I can't run any command (nothing happens on enter))

```
[10.175214] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Setting dpms mode 0 on vga encoder (output 0)
[10.175223] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Output VGA-1 is running on CRTC 0 using output 0
[10.181152] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[10.188268] registered panic notifier
[10.188302] [drm] Initialized nouveau 0.0.15 20090420 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
```

After few times of inactivity, this lines show up too:

```
udevadm settle - timeout of 180 seconds reached, the event queue contains:
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.1/host0/target0:0:1/0:0:1:0/block/sda (718)
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.1/host0/target0:0:1/0:0:1:0/block/sda/sda1 (719)
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.1/host0/target0:0:1/0:0:1:0/block/sda/sda2 (720)
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.1/host0/target0:0:1/0:0:1:0/block/sda/sda5 (721)
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.1/host0/target0:0:1/0:0:1:0/block/sda/sda6 (722)
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.1/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sdb (731)
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.1/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sdb1 (732)
done (timeout).
udevd[294]: worker [327] unexpectedly returned with status 0x0100

udevd[294]: worker [327] failed while loading '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.1/host0/target0:0:1/0:0:1:0/block/sda'

udevd[294]: worker [317] unexpectedly returned with status 0x0100

udevd[294]: worker [317] failed while loading '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.1/host0/target0:0:1/0:0:1:0/block/sdb'
```

What can I do to fix this?

---

**UPDATE**

<strike>I have downloaded `/var/log/messages` from that computer</strike>
(It was bad file from live linux, not from the one installed on my computer, there isn't seems to be any related info/errors in the right "messages" file, I'm not sure it could help)

**UPDATE2:** I have run `e2fsck` on both of my ext partitions (sda), but **exit code was 0** (no error)

**UPDATE3:** I just tried to ["repair" filesystem using alternate superblock](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/recover-bad-superblock-from-corrupted-partition/), I was successful but nothing changed :(. What more can I try?

Comment: It seems to be complaining that `/dev/sda` doesn't come up. That is your primary disk? Have you tried to boot in single user mode? A LiveCD/installation media as rescue, so any hash you might have made with the configuration isn't an issue?

Comment: I have tried hiren's CD live linux, I was able to mount my primary disk. So the disk isn't broken, I dont know what may be wrong with it, filesystem seems to be ok as I am able to view and edit files. What means "single user mode" and what "hash" can I provide to help solve this?

Comment: I've just tried booting in single user mode, but I was unsuccessful

Comment: It's a wild notion, but i had similar symptoms...  examine your fstab entries closely.  i had one errant "auto" which prevented my machine from booting (with a wholely unhelpful error message).  Consider commenting out everything not essential to booting the machine, (likely a single partition?), and see if that allows it to boot.  good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to boot in single mode by adding the value `rw single` instead of the `ro quiet` to the kernel line in grub bootloader.

If that do not help you spin up either dvd or usb with some live linux system on it and boot into it after that you should do the `chroot` into your installation by mounting your / partition on /mnt on the live system for example.

And then mount additional partitions you have as much as I see from your logs you have 4 partitions on the sda and one on sdb.
so mount your /boot partition to /mnt/boot home is not needed but if you have separate /var or /usr partitions you should mount them too to the respective places in /mnt.

You should check your /etc/fstab and see whether that /dev/sdb disk or some other is connected to the system while booting. All you need to boot your system are / partition and any other like /boot or /usr /var nothing else so you might want to comment out other partitions and try booting again.

If you are booting via UUID which is now common for most of the Linux operating systems then make sure that the partitions have correct UUID set up in /etc/fstab if you ware deleting some of them or changing the UUID's then that might be a problem.

You can run check of individual partitions with `blkid /dev/sdXn` where X is the letter of the drive and n is the number of partition.

Also while you are on the live system you could run `smartctl -a /dev/sda` and `smartctl -a /dev/sdb` that will give you relevant S.M.A.R.T. information about your hdd's look for uncorectable sectors and sectors pending and reallocated sectors.
In case those values are more then 0 and especially near 100 you might want to change the hdd because its hardware is failing.

Answer (score -3):

you must blacklist nouveau drivers. I don't wanna be the smartest guy in class. But you probably are trying to use Kali Linux. And this problem pcspkr' is new because now is created on debian. But problems with nouveau drivers are old, so read a little more about this on BackTrack forums.

Comment: I have tried blacklisting nouveau, but didnt helped, Im still unable to boot my pc (see http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/attachment.php?attachmentid=12087&d=1363726139 )